# Drawing to images/textures in html5

Tags: image, html, canvas, textures

**The situation**: I'm creating a game where every player has its snake.

**The problem**: Under special circumstances, a players snake could be of more than thousand arcs. I redraw the canvas on every tick (I try to get 60fps). Now, because there are too much arcs to draw, it gets very slow.

**My idea**: Draw the snake of every player to an image/texture, and only redraw the whole image for each player on the canvas.

**My question**: Is this possible? When yes, what do I have to search for? I'm not that experienced in game development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest looking into the `context.createPattern` method. You can dynamically create a new canvas and draw your complex image on it. After you're done drawing once, you can call `context.createPattern(dynamicCanvas, 'no-repeat')` and then keep a reference to that pattern around. Then anytime you want to draw that snake, translate your context to the appropriate location and set the `context.fillStyle` to be your pattern and fill in a rectangle that fits your pattern. Here's some generalized code:

```
// Only do this once per unique snake, not per frame
var patternCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
// Set the size to be the minimum size to draw your snake on
patternCanvas.width = 100;
patternCanvas.height = 100;
// code that draws snake onto patternCanvas here
// ...

// Create the pattern
var pattern = patternCanvas.getContext("2d").createPattern(patternCanvas, "no-repeat");

// Using your real canvas that's drawing every frame
var realContext = realCanvas.getContext("2d");
realContext.save();
realContext.translate(50, 80); // x, y coordinates of where you want to draw your snake
realContext.fillStyle = pattern;
realContext.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100); // The last two parameters are your width and height of your snake pattern
realContext.restore();
```

Notice that `createPattern` can take an entire canvas object and you never need to append the `patternCanvas` to a DOM object, so it acts like a back-buffer.

When drawing your patterns, try to draw them all within the same `save`/`restore`. Just keep translating and filling rectangles. Each `save`/`restore` and modification to the `context` will slow you down, so you want to make sure you are batching calls as much as possible.

There can be any number of reasons for why Canvas may be drawing slow, so I'd recommend following some of the ideas mentioned at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/.

Comment: Thanks for this. I found out that using drawImage(canvas_as_texture, x, y) is _much_ more fast than using the createPattern method (I'm speaking of the situation where you have to re-create the pattern every frame).